# delaying a function to execute jquery

Tags: jquery, delay

I want a button pressed, then the button changes style, and a new function loads, after about 1/2 second of the styling.

```
$(document).on('click', '.capital_answers', function(){
    if(!$('#capital_answers').hasClass('answered')) {
        answer = $(this).attr('data-answer');
        if(answer==1) {
            $(this).addClass('capital_correct');
            $('#capital_answers').addClass('answered');
            capital_correct()
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('capital_wrong');
            $('#capital_answers').addClass('answered');
        }
    delay(500).capital_next();  
    }
});
```

So as you can see I am using the delay() method currently, which helps in no way. What options are there in delaying a function in this manner?

Comment: `capital_next()` called with delay. So what is your problem?

Comment: what is `capital_next()`? is it a plugin? Is it a function? You have it chained to a function `delay()` which isn't even defined. Look in your console at errors thrown...what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)**

Change:

```
delay(500).capital_next();
```

To

```
setTimeout(function(){
   capital_next();
}, 500);
```

this assumes that `capital_next()` is a standalone function. It's not clear from code in question